# MS Access-like Flutter Combo Box

Tags: ms-access, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and want to add a drop down list similar to an Access Combo Box, with a text field you can type in which will display a list of values you can select from or autocomplete to.

I'm currently just learning the front end, so if you write an example it'd be best if the data source was just a simple list.

Thanks.

Comment: @June7 no I know how to do drop down lists, but they simply show a list of options when you click the box. I want a box that you can type in that also has a drop down list filtered based on your input. MS Access has combo boxes that are what I'm used to and want.

Comment: So Flutter is the development interface but what language are you coding - C#, C++?

Comment: @June7 if you don't know what something is you're better off not trying to answer something about it.

Comment: @June7 Flutter is a Framework developed by Google that uses the Dart programming language, it's not an IDE. I appreciate you trying to help but you shouldn't try and help on something you don't know the first thing about.

Comment: https://github.com/hpoul/dart-autocomplete-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead

A TypeAhead (autocomplete) widget for Flutter, where you can show suggestions to users as they type

you can see full example code here https://github.com/AbdulRahmanAlHamali/flutter_typeahead/tree/master/example

[image]